# Unable to get dependency information when running mvn jetty:run

Tags: maven

I cloned a project from github and try to build it. Follow its instruction I run `mvn package` but when I try to run `mvn jetty:run`. It failed and give me:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Unable to get dependency information: Unable to read the metadata file for artifact 'org.mortbay.jasper:apache-jsp:jar': Cannot find parent: org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-parent for project: org.mortbay.jasper:jasper-jsp:pom:8.0.9.M3 for project org.mortbay.jasper:jasper-jsp:pom:8.0.9.M3
  org.mortbay.jasper:apache-jsp:jar:8.0.9.M3
```

Why this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade maven to version 3 or higher. I had maven 2.2.1, then I upgraded it to 3.3.9 and this issue was solved.

Also use JDK 1.7 or higher.